# find xpath for sibling node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to get the value of name where map is anything.
I dont want iterate and then find. Is there any way we can write xpath for the same?

What will be the xpath for node which is having `map = sec2`? Please find the xml below.

```
 <section-meta-data>
            <section>
                <name>Applicant Info</name>
                <map>sec1</map>
            </section>
            <section>
                <name>prior-insurance-coverage</name>
                <map>sec3</map>
            </section>
            <section>
                <name>hipaa-guarantee-issue-coverage</name>
                <map>sec2</map>
            </section>
            <section>
                <name>medical-info</name>
                <map>sec7</map>
            </section>
            <section>
                <name>medications</name>
                <map>sec4</map>
            </section>
        </section-meta-data>
```

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="/form/section-mappings/section-meta-data/section[map.=$sectionMap]/name"> .. is the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
/section-meta-data/section[map='sec2']/name
```